# List files with absolute path recursive in linux

Tags: linux, bash

This question is quite similar to [How can I list files with their absolute path in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-list-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux)

I want to get the name of file or folder with absolute path and date modified.

This command almost does it:

```
ls -lR /foo/bar | awk '{print $6,$7,$8,$9}'
```

But it doesnt show the absolute path.

Regards
Stollan

Comment: Never parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: Regard pitfalls of parsing `ls` output. 
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937716/how-do-you-send-the-output-of-ls-to-mv
and 
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the `find` command and its `printf` option.

```
find /foo/bar -printf "%p %A@"
```

See the man page of `find` for more information.

Comment: `find /directory -name "hello" -type f -print -exec date -r {} +%Y/%D:%H:%M \;` another way, won't give it as answer because yours is good.

Comment: You might want a `\n`. `%A` is access time - the OP asked for modified time which is `%T`. The `@` gives seconds since the epoch. If you want a more human-readable date/time, use: `%T+` or `%TY-%Tm-%Td %TX` or similar. I'd put the date first for easier fixed-width parsing. So, finally: `find /foo/bar -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TX\t%p\n"`

Answer (score -1):

I like to use:

```
ls -d -1 $PWD/**
```

Comment: True I guess. So only use this if you don't want to include files in directories inside the current directory.

Comment: this is exactly answer I was looking for... well, the /** part, in my case ls -lahrt /logdir1/** /logdir2/** - show hidden [a], human size [h], show modified on bottom [rt - reverse time]

Answer (score -1):

After reading some partial solutions no recursion, partial date format, no pipe... my proposition is from the target folder:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -lAoUtTh {} \; | awk '{print $9"\t"$5"\/"$6"\/"$8"\t"$7"\t"$4}' | grep -E -i '.*\.fcp\b|.*\.omf\b'
```

Works well thanks to contributors but very slowly basicly me.

Gilles

OsX Darwin 10.8 bash