# How to move all files with a specified owner in Unix?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

I have a directory with a large number of files, and I need to separate them by owner. My instinct was to pipe `ls` output to `mv`, but I've seen that that is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937716/how-do-you-send-the-output-of-ls-to-mv) due to the possibility that filenames could contain special characters. In any case, the closest I can think of is:

`ls -l | grep OWNER | find regex_for_filename | mv ../`

but this does not work.

Note - I do have a reliable regex for files within the directory, but the ownership is scattered.

Comment: `find -maxdepth 1 -user username -exec mv {} ../ \;`, omit the maxdepth if you need it from subdirectories as well.

Comment: @Wrikken why not put that in an answer?

Comment: You want the list files on the command line of mv, not in its standard input. So a pipe doesn't make sense. Find, like in @Wrikkens example, is the best way to do this

Comment: @rainkinz: well, question #a couple of thousands where the answer is "use find", I have the hope someone has energy enough to close this as a duplicate :P

Comment: @Wrikken This is what I am looking for. This answer could help out those who, like me, mixed up the keyword "owner" with "user."

Comment: @Wrikken Agreed with OP that this could probably help some people looking for the specific problem, unlike all the "quote your variables to prevent word-splitting..." questions, where if you know how to describe the problem you know how to fix it.

Comment: Ah, well, upgraded it to an answer then ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -user username -exec mv {} ../ \;
```

Omit the maxdepth if you need files from subdirectories.