# How can I store the "find" command results as an array in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, find

I am trying to save the result from `find` as arrays.
Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "input : "
read input

echo "searching file with this pattern '${input}' under present directory"
array=`find . -name ${input}`

len=${#array[*]}
echo "found : ${len}"

i=0

while [ $i -lt $len ]
do
echo ${array[$i]}
let i++
done
```

I get 2 .txt files under current directory.
So I expect '2' as result of `${len}`. However, it prints 1.
The reason is that it takes all result of `find` as one elements.
How can I fix this?

P.S
I found several solutions on StackOverFlow about a similar problem. However, they are a little bit different so I can't apply in my case. I need to store the results in a variable before the loop. Thanks again.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

### Update 2020 for Linux Users:

If you have an up-to-date version of bash (4.4-alpha or better), as you probably do if you are on Linux, then you should be using [Benjamin W.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54561526/3030305).

If you are on Mac OS, which —last I checked— still used bash 3.2, or are otherwise using an older bash, then continue on to the next section.

### Answer for bash 4.3 or earlier

Here is one solution for getting the output of `find` into a `bash` array:

```
array=()
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    array+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find . -name "${input}" -print0)
```

This is tricky because, in general, file names can have spaces, new lines, and other script-hostile characters.  The only way to use `find` and have the file names safely separated from each other is to use `-print0` which prints the file names separated with a null character.  This would not be much of an inconvenience if bash's `readarray`/`mapfile` functions supported null-separated strings but they don't.  Bash's `read` does and that leads us to the loop above.

*[This answer was originally written in 2014.  If you have a recent version of bash, please see the update below.]*

#### How it works

1. The first line creates an empty array: `array=()`
2. Every time that the `read` statement is executed, a null-separated file name is read from standard input.  The `-r` option tells `read` to leave backslash characters alone.  The `-d $'\0'` tells `read` that the input will be null-separated.  Since we omit the name to `read`, the shell puts the input into the default name: `REPLY`.
3. The `array+=("$REPLY")` statement appends the new file name to the array `array`.
4. The final line combines redirection and command substitution to provide the output of `find` to the standard input of the `while` loop.

#### Why use process substitution?

If we didn't use process substitution, the loop could be written as:

```
array=()
find . -name "${input}" -print0 >tmpfile
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    array+=("$REPLY")
done <tmpfile
rm -f tmpfile
```

In the above the output of `find` is stored in a temporary file and that file is used as standard input to the while loop.  The idea of process substitution is to make such temporary files unnecessary.  So, instead of having the `while` loop get its stdin from `tmpfile`, we can have it get its stdin from `<(find . -name ${input} -print0)`.

Process substitution is widely useful.  In many places where a command wants to *read* from a file, you can specify process substitution, `<(...)`, instead of a file name.  There is an analogous form, `>(...)`, that can be used in place of a file name where the command wants to *write* to the file.

Like arrays, process substitution is a feature of bash and other advanced shells.  It is not part of the POSIX standard.

#### Alternative: lastpipe

If desired, `lastpipe` can be used instead of process substitution (hat tip: [Caesar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401059/caesar)):

```
set +m
shopt -s lastpipe
array=()
find . -name "${input}" -print0 | while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do array+=("$REPLY"); done; declare -p array
```

`shopt -s lastpipe` tells bash to run the last command in the pipeline in the current shell (not the background).  This way, the `array` remains in existence after the pipeline completes.  Because `lastpipe` only takes effect if job control is turned off, we run `set +m`.  (In a script, as opposed to the command line, job control is off by default.)

#### Additional notes

The following command creates a shell variable, not a shell array:

```
array=`find . -name "${input}"`
```

If you wanted to create an array, you would need to put parens around the output of find.  So, naively, one could:

```
array=(`find . -name "${input}"`)  # don't do this
```

The problem is that the shell performs word splitting on the results of `find` so that the elements of the array are not guaranteed to be what you want.

#### Update 2019

Starting with version 4.4-alpha, bash now supports a `-d` option so that the above loop is no longer necessary.  Instead, one can use:

```
mapfile -d $'\0' array < <(find . -name "${input}" -print0)
```

For more information on this, please see (and upvote) [Benjamin W.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54561526/3030305).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. But could you explain little more about last line? I mean redirection part. At first, I write "<<" and it show syntax error on "(". After several tries, I just copy your code to mine and it works. what is the meaning of '<' in last line?

Comment: @JuneyoungOh Glad it helped.  I added a section of process substitution.

Comment: I think the `IFS=` part before `read` is useless. From `man read`: "**...the first word is assigned to the first name, the second word to the second name, and so on, with leftover words and their  intervening  separators  assigned  to the last name...The characters in IFS are used to split the line into words**", and "**If no names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable REPLY**". Since there's no argument supplied, the whole line is assigned to the only variable `REPLY`. The word separator specified by `IFS` is not useful here, because the line is not at all split into words.

Comment: @Rockallite That is a good observation but incomplete.  While it is true that we don't split into multiple words, we still need `IFS=` to avoid removal of whitespace from the beginnings or ends of the input lines.  You can test this easily by comparing the output of  `read var <<<' abc ';  echo ">$var<"` with the output of `IFS= read var <<<' abc ';  echo ">$var<"`.  In the former case, the spaces before and after `abc` are removed.  In the latter, they aren't.  File names that begin or end with whitespace may be unusual but, it they exist, we want them processed correctly.

Comment: Hi, after i execute your code i get message
syntax error near unexpected token `<'
`done < <(find aaa/ -not -newermt "$last_build_timestamp_v" -type f -print0)'

Comment: @PrzemysławSienkiewicz I would need to see more details on what you are doing to be sure but, on many systems, the default shell doesn't support either process substitution or arrays.  One may need to explicitly invoke the script with bash like `bash scriptname`.   If that doesn't solve it, then a good next step is to run your script through [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).  (Just cut-and-paste your script into shellcheck's window and wait a moment for a response.)

Comment: How do you adjust this such that the array entries are not the full file path but only the file name?

Comment: @Zuks Use `-printf` like: `while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do     array+=("$REPLY"); done < <(find . -name "${input}" -printf '%f\0')`

Comment: @John1024 I actually tried this a number of times. It does not seem to add the elements into the array when using printf '%f\0'

Comment: @zuks It worked fine for me.  I just copied-and-pasted from my comment to the command line and it still works for me.  __Did you have the variable `input` set to a useful value?__  To make sure that all the variables are initialized, try `input='*'; array=(); while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'; do array+=("$REPLY"); done < <(find . -name "${input}" -printf '%f\0')`

Comment: A note: the simpler `''` can be used instead of `$'\0'`: `n=0; while IFS= read -r -d '' line || [ "$line" ]; do echo "$((++n)):$line"; done < <(printf 'first\nstill first\0second\0third')`

Comment: How do I pipe the find output to cut then have those results added to the array?  I would like to use something like`find /DIRECTORY -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -f5 -d'/'` in the `done` line.

Comment: @lordhog Yes, you can put any useful command in the process substitution as long as it produces NUL-separated output.  After switching from newline to NUL-separation, your command, if you are using GNU tools, becomes `find 1/2/3/4 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%p\0' | cut -zf5 -d'/'`.

Comment: @theeagle I assume that you intended to write `BLAH=$(find . -name '*.php')`.  As discussed in the answer, that approach will work in limited cases but it won't work in general with all filenames and it doesn't produce, as the OP expected, an _array_.

Comment: Might be worth to mention the `shopt -s lastpipe` trick to make `find | while read …` work. (Note that that may not work in interactive mode, only in a script file, for reasons that are beyond me.)

Comment: @Caesar Interesting idea.  Thanks!  I added `lastpipe` to the answer.  (By the way, in interactive mode, job control is on by default and job control disables `lastpipe`.  This can be overcome by running `set +m` to disable job control.)

Comment: The 2019 version doesn't work for me with `-print0`. It works if I use `mapfile -d$'\n'` with `-print`.

Comment: @maharvey67 Do you use GNU find?

Comment: @John1024  i have a function which  uses the find query to list all the files in the sub directory . `find $1 -type f -follow` works what i need . I then  tried to save the results with `array=()` and then `mapfile -d$'\0' array < <(find $1 -type f -follow -print0)` . But `echo ${array[*]}` does not give me anything , where i am getting it wrong ? I am using GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: @warrior_monk  That's my fault: there was a space missing in the command.  Try: `mapfile -d $'\0' array < <(find "$1" -type f -follow -print0)` with a space between `-d` and `$'\0'`.   Separately, in case the directory name `$1` might contain whitespace or other difficult characters, it's best to put it in double-quotes like `"$1"`.

Comment: @John1024 ,even `mapfile -d $'\0' array < <(find "$1" -type f -follow -print0)` does not work . I can confirm that `find "$1" -type f -follow -print0` does work however . It gives me list of all the files in the directories and sub-directories.

Comment: @warrior_monk That's frustrating.  I just cut-and-paste your command and it works for me.  I'm using bash 5.0.3.  To make sure that the command is truly running under bash, please try `bash -c 'mapfile -d $'\0' array < <(find . -type f -follow -print0); declare -p array'`

Comment: @warrior_monk Are you the command in a script?  If so, what is the shebang line and how are you executing the script?

Comment: @John1024 I have created a script called temp.sh . The contents are `#!/bin/bash
list_allFiles(){
mapfile -d $'\0' array < <(find "$1" -type f -follow -print0)
} 
echo ${array[0]}
dir=/home/abhishek/Desktop/CountryNames 
list_allFiles "$dir"` 
And i am running the script with the command `bash temp.sh` in the terminal .

Comment: @warrior_monk Thanks! That makes it clear:  the command `echo ${array[0]}` is executed after the function `list_allFiles` is __defined__ but before it is __executed__.  Move the `echo` command to the line __after__ the line `list_allFiles "$dir"`.

Comment: @BenjaminW.Yes it is GNU find. `-d$'\0'` (no space) does not work, but `-d $'\0'` (with a space) does work with `-print0`. `-d $'\0'` seems equivalent to `-d ''` perhaps because `\0` looks the same as an empty string in C.  The `-d$'\n'` works with `-print`, with or without a space between.  Also... this is a very useful technique, thanks so much!

Comment: Why are there two spaces after `IFS=`?

Comment: @John1024 Is there something wrong with the following approach? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63969005/4579271

Comment: @sunknudsen Newline characters are legal in file names.  The approach in that link works as long as no file name contains a newline character.  If the file names are all names that you created and you know that they don't have newlines, then that approach may be 'good enough.'  That kind of approach, however, is often not popular on SO where programmers typically place great value on code that is known to work _always_.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks for the feedback! Very appreciated. Do you know of any solution that works both using Bash and Z Shell?

Comment: @sunknudsen You're welcome.  I don't know of such a solution but I'm not the right person to answer that: my knowledge of Z Shell is limited.

Answer (score 122):

Bash 4.4 introduced a `-d` option to `readarray`/`mapfile`, so this can now be solved with

```
readarray -d '' array < <(find . -name "$input" -print0)
```

for a method that works with arbitrary filenames including blanks, newlines, and globbing characters. This requires that your `find` supports `-print0`, as for example GNU find does.

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) (omitting other options):

> ```
> mapfile [-d delim] [array]
> ```
>
> `-d`
> The first character of *`delim`* is used to terminate each input line, rather than newline. If *`delim`* is the empty string, `mapfile` will terminate a line when it reads a NUL character.

And `readarray` is just a synonym of `mapfile`.

Comment: This is great, I've already given it a +1. There's one caveat though -- if the command inside the process substitution fails, the exit code of the overall command is still 0. Is there a good way to have the exit code propagated to the outer command?

Comment: @dpritch Inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176703/118235), you could print the exit status as part of the process substitution: `readarray -d '' array < <(find . -name "$input" -print0; printf "$?")`,  and then examine the last array element: `echo "${array[-1]}"`.

Comment: ^^ This is brilliant!

Answer (score 42):

The following appears to work for both Bash and Z Shell on macOS.

```sh
#! /bin/sh

IFS=$'\n'
paths=($(find . -name "foo"))
unset IFS

printf "%s\n" "${paths[@]}"
```

Comment: This works with files having spaces and other special characters, fails with the (admittedly rare) case of files having a linebreak in their name. You can create one for a test with `printf "%b" "file name with spaces, a star * ...\012and a second line\0" | xargs -0 touch `

Comment: maybe I'm missing something here, but this seems like the much clearer, easier solution for 99% of cases

Comment: Definitely works great for zsh on macOS Big Sur :) thanks! - but I also know my fileset has no names with newlines, because who does that? I have never seen one in the wild and I made the files so I know its not an issue.

Comment: Newlines are an issue in case the script may operate on files that are supplied by a potentially malicious user. For a hypothetical example, if your system ran something like `detect-malware "${paths[@]}"`, a virus could be smuggled past this defense by including a newline in its name.

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 20):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, you can replace your use of `find` with

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
array=( **/*"$input"* )
```

The `**` pattern enabled by `globstar` matches 0 or more directories, allowing the pattern to match to an arbitrary depth in the current directory. Without the `nullglob` option, the pattern (after parameter expansion) is treated literally, so with no matches you would have an array with a single string rather than an empty array.

Add the `dotglob` option to the first line as well if you want to traverse hidden directories (like `.ssh`) and match hidden files (like `.bashrc`) as well.

Comment: Maybe `nullglob` too…

Comment: Yeah, I always forget that.

Comment: Note that this will not include the hidden files and directories, unless `dotglob` is set (this may or may not be wanted, but it's worth mentioning too).

Comment: This looks very useful, unless you actually need `find`'s more interesting file matching features which aren't name glob based (for example, find by type, date, etc).

Comment: Indeed. `find` still has it uses (unless you are using `zsh`, in which case I think just about anything `find` can do you can do with some unreadable set of glob qualifiers :) )

Answer (score 13):

you can try something like

```
array=(`find . -type f | sort -r | head -2`)
```

, and in order to print the array values , you can try something like echo `"${array[*]}"`

Comment: Breaks if there are filenames with spaces or glob characters.

Answer (score 2):

None of these solutions suited me because I didn't feel like learning readarray and mapfile.  Here is what I came up with.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "input : "
read input

echo "searching file with this pattern '${input}' under present directory"
# The only change is here. Append to array for each non-empty line.
array=()
while read line; do
    [[ ! -z "$line" ]] && array+=("$line")
done; <<< $(find . -name ${input} -print)

len=${#array[@]}
echo "found : ${len}"

i=0

while [ $i -lt $len ]
do
echo ${array[$i]}
let i++
done
```

Comment: I like this one. But shellcheck asked me to remove the semicolon in this line `done; <<<`

Answer (score -1):

You could do like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "input : "
read input

echo "searching file with this pattern '${input}' under present directory"
array=(`find . -name '*'${input}'*'`)

for i in "${array[@]}"
do :
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Thanks. a lot. But as @anishsane pointed, empty spaces in filename should be considered in my program. Anyway Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

In bash, `$(<any_shell_cmd>)` helps to run a command and capture the output. Passing this to `IFS` with `\n` as delimiter helps to convert that to an array.

```
IFS='\n' read -r -a txt_files <<< $(find /path/to/dir -name "*.txt")
```

Comment: This will get only the first file of the results of `find` into the array.