# How to create tar for files older than 7 days using linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell

I'm writing shell script to backup files older than 7 days. Here is my code. But i'm not getting expected result. Can anyone correct me?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Backup files

files=($(find /var/log/ -mtime +"7"))
 for files in ${files[*]}
 do
         echo $files
         tar cvfz backup.tar.gz $files
 done
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will work:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=()
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    files+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find /var/log/ -mtime +7 -print0)
tar cvfz backup.tar.gz "${files[@]}"
```

Note the use of `"${files[@]}"` as opposed to `${files[*]}`.  `"${files[@]}"` will expand to provide `tar` with one argument per file name and will work even if the file names contain spaces, tabs, or newlines.  By contrast, after the shell expands `${files[*]}`, it will perform word splitting, potentially mangling your file names.

For a detailed explanation of the loop used to create the `files` array, see: [How can I store find command result as arrays in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23357277/3030305)

All files and directories produced by the command `find /var/log/ -mtime +7` will be included in the `tar` file.  To include only files, not directories, see Skynet's answer.

#### To archive logs from the seven most recent days

Only one character need change:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=()
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    files+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find /var/log/ -mtime -7 -print0)
tar cvfz backup.tar.gz "${files[@]}"
```

This works because `find` interprets numeric arguments as follows:

> Numeric arguments can be specified as
>          +n     for greater than n,
>          -n     for less than n,
>          n      for exactly n.

Thus, `-mtime +7` means greater than 7 days old while `-mtime -7` means less than 7.  Note that `find` will ignore fractional parts.  Thus `+7` will include 8 days old but not 7.5 days old.  See `man find` for details.

Comment: just now noticed its looping continuously. Iteration is not getting stopped. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: @Palanikumar My version has no loops and no iterations, just two commands.  One defines the file list and the other tars the files.  So, please tell me what you are seeing.  If you are uncertain what is happening, put `set -x` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: If you are still receiving error, try modifying the IFS: 
 
# save and change IFS 
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
 
# read all file name into an array
fileArray=($(find $DIR -type f))
 
# restore it 
IFS=$OLDIFS  
 
Found the solution on 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html

Answer (score 4):

Replace your `find` command with this and try again,

```
find /var/log -type f -mtime +7
```

Comment: -7  but +1 for the answer :)

Comment: last 7 days into a zip file: 
```
find /yourpath/ -type f -mtime -7 -print | zip dump.zip -@
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but in searching for a similar solution, I found this simple line to work nicely:

```
find /var/log -mtime +7 | xargs tar -zcvf archive.tar.gz
```

Using `xargs` allows the output of `find` to make their way into the archive.