# Find files in current directory sorted by modified time and store result in an array

Tags: bash, shell

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong in following shell function?

```
NOTES_PATH="/home/temp"

function open_note {

    local files=()                                                          
    while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0' filename; do                                        
        files+=("$filename")                                                   
    done < <(find "$NOTES_PATH" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t)

    echo "There is/are ${#files[@]} file(s) available"
}
```

I get "There is/are 0 file(s) available" everytime even though I can see 2 text files in /home/temp directory.

Please note that I want to use while loop approach to read filenames, not any other way unless I cannot achieve what I want to do. [credits: [John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356779/how-can-i-store-find-command-result-as-arrays-in-bash) answer]

P.S. If I run `find /home/temp -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -t` from command line, I get expected result.

Comment: `-d $'\0'` is the same as `-d ''`. I don't know what specifying an empty read delimiter does.

Comment: that input coming from `find` command will be null seperated

Comment: That input comes from `ls`, not `find`. And no, it won't be.

Comment: If `find` emits more filenames than will fit one one `ls -t` command, they won't in fact be correctly sorted. `ls` has no place whatsoever for automated use.

Comment: Aside: `NOTE_PATH` shouldn't be all-uppercase. POSIX conventions for variable names have all-uppercase names reserved for variables with meaning to POSIX-specified tools (thus, the shell or other operating system components). This is most explicitly specified for environment variables, but since setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, the convention necessarily applies there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code had several bugs:

- The advantages of NUL-delimiting content prior to `xargs -0` were lost, because the output of `ls -t` was not NUL-delimited.
- Because `xargs` split results into multiple `ls -t` invocations, sorting took place only within these batches: Given enough filenames to require two or more invocations, those invocations would only be individually sorted, not globally sorted.
- Parsing output of `ls` is [generally error-prone](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

---

A cleaner implementation (assuming GNU find and GNU sort) would look like the following:

```
open_note() {
  local filename mtime
  local -a files=( )

  while IFS= read -r -d' ' mtime && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
    files+=( "$filename" )
  done < <(find "$NOTES_PATH" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %P\0' | sort -z -n)
}
```

The `find` action given emits a stream of the format:

```
<epoch time> <filename><NUL>
```

...which `sort` then sorts on, after which the `while read` loop discards the first part of each field.

---

A few other notes:

- Don't use the `function` keyword; it makes your code gratuitously incompatible with POSIX sh, but (unlike other, more useful bashisms) adds no advantage whatsoever over the compliant syntax.
- If you're trying to keep your locals scoped, be sure that you get *all* of them -- that includes names being looped over.

Comment: Assume that null-delimiting was originally applied to handle whitespaced filenames..

Comment: @vp_arth, ...and that contradicts anything I said how? Using `ls` (without an implementation implementing the currently-proposal-stage `-0` flag) is still throwing away that advantage: A filename with a literal newline will be indistinguishable from two separate names (or will have that newline replaced by a placeholder character, meaning that the output doesn't correctly represent the file's name) in the output from `ls -t`.

Comment: @vp_arth, ...if you're referring only to those advantages that could be also gained (on GNU platforms) with `xargs -d $'\n'` with conventional newline-delimited content, then I grant that you have a point, but it's silly to fix only a subset of corner cases when there's a readily-available way to fix all of them.

Comment: Your answer is awesome. I just can't to understand, why you still use `\0` as delimiter(and `sort -z`), while `read` and `sort` both have default '\n'?

Comment: @vp_arth, a newline literal can be present in a filename. NUL is the only character that can't.

Comment: @vp_arth, ...moreover, if you have a directory that multiple users have access to, filenames can easily constitute a privilege boundary, and thus be a point of interest for security purposes. If someone runs `mkdir -p $'/tmp/\n/etc/passwd'`, you don't want a script cleaning out cruft from `/tmp` to get confused about what's a standalone filename and what isn't. (I've seen data loss events caused by buffer overflows throwing content into filenames that wasn't even *intentionally* malicious; it's very much worth cultivating defensive habits).

Comment: `touch $(echo -e '/tmp/test\0zero')` just skips a null... Good to know, thanks :)

Comment: @vp_arth, no POSIX system will let you create a file named `/tmp/test<NUL>zero`, where that `<NUL>` is a literal NUL, so it's moot: the building blocks of UNIX are NUL-terminated strings, so you can't have a literal NUL within them. Whether the NUL gets skipped or truncates the output varies on circumstances (what you demonstrated above is specifically bash-local command substitution behavior), but it'll always be one of the two.

Comment: @vp_arth, ...on a different point, consider using `printf` instead of `echo -e` -- bash literally violates the POSIX standard by having it do anything other than print `-e` on output (most extensions are in undefined space, but this one is actually a violation, and moreover goes away when both posix and xpg_echo flags are enabled, making it unreliable even on bash). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for detailed answer. wouldn't it be more appropriate to reduce while loop condition to `IFS=$' ' read -r -d'' mtime filename`. I executed the script with this condition and it did not change global value of IFS.

Comment: Correct, it won't change the global value of IFS, but it does trim trailing whitespace from filenames.

Comment: @shaffooo, ...actually, there's a bigger bug in there too: `-d''` generates exactly the same argv as `-d`, so you're consuming the `mtime` argument and making `m` the record delimiter. The whitespace in `-d ''` is critical.