# Listing files, sorted by time, only when prefix matches a line in a file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file with 2 characters in each line, like this:

```
RU    
8A   
1C
```

How can I read those characters into a unix command (in this case, forming an argument list for `ls -t`)? I want something like this:

```
ls -t RU* 8A* 1C*
```

Comment: Piping `ls` commands to each other doesn't make any sense. `ls` doesn't read from stdin, so output from all but the last will just be ignored.

Comment: Assuming `ls` is just a placeholder, though -- do you want to change the number of pipeline elements based on the number of lines in the file? Is it intentional that the last line *isn't* used as a wildcard prefix?

Comment: the characters in the file are prefixes that i want to use in a ls - t command, the content in the file can differ from time to time, so i need the command to be dynamic

Comment: Again, your `ls -t` pipeline shown in the question *doesn't actually work*. It ignores all but the last line. If you want to show us what you want to do, show us something that works; we can't infer intent from broken code.

Comment: (Also, [parsing output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is generally error-prone; if you want to sort a bunch of files by date, there are better ways to do it).

Comment: It should be a ls -t command but with a filter on RU*,  8A* and so on

Comment: Three separate invocations of `ls -t`, sorted individually? One, sorted together? And, again, `ls -t` output should never be parsed -- it's tool that's adequately specified only for human consumption of output, since its handling of unusual filenames is implementation-defined.

Comment: Maybe `ls -t RU* ; ls -t 8A* ; ls -t 1C*` or `ls -t RU* 8A* 1C*`

Comment: Or it could be that they want `ls -t RU* 8A* 1C*`. We don't know, because the OP isn't telling us.

Comment: ls -t RU* 8A* 1C*  tested it.  This is exactly what i need, sry for responding so late

Comment: Note that `ls -t RU* 8A* 1C*` will fail if you give it more arguments than will fit on a single command line. (Where that limit is varies by operating system, and on the number and size of environment variables you have exported, which count against the same limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want three separate runs of `ls`:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  ls -t "$line"*
done <input_file.txt
```

If you want just one run, with all the content globbed together:

```
set --
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [ -n "$line" ] || continue
  set -- "$@" "$line"*
done <input_file.txt
ls -t "$@"
```

---

**Note that `ls -t` is an unreliable tool.** It won't work if you pass it more filenames than can be given to a single command invocation (and attempts to make it work using `xargs` will give you multiple, individually-sorted lists in output). If on a platform with GNU tools (bash, and GNU `find` and `sort`), consider the following instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

predicates=( -false )
while IFS= read -r line; do
  predicates+=( -o -name "${line}*" )
done <input_file.txt

while IFS= read -r -d' ' mtime && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  echo "Processing file $filename with timestamp $mtime"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 '(' "${predicates[@]}" ')' -printf '%T@ %P\0' | sort -z -n)
```

---

Useful links:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - *How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?*
- [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) - *How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute (newest / oldest modification time, size, etc)?*
- [Find files in current directory sorted by modified time and store result in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982088/find-files-in-current-directory-sorted-by-modified-time-and-store-result-in-an-a)

Comment: Had a bug in the `find` version earlier -- I'd switched from populating `"$@"` to using an array named `predicates`, but wasn't expanding that array onto the `find` command line. See the recent edit.