# How to remove all occurences of a string with `/` from another string

Tags: shell

I have string which looks like this:

`/mnt/blumeta0/db2/head/home/db2inst1/sqllib/ctrlha/ /mnt/blumeta0/db2/head/home/db2inst1/sqllib/ctrl/ /mnt/blumeta0/db2/head/home/db2inst1/sqllib/log/ /mnt/blumeta0/db2/head/home/db2inst1/sqllib/cfg/`

This is stored in variable `sqllib_files_folders` in the script below : I am trying to remove all occurences of prefix `TMP_SOTRAGE` which is `/mnt/blumeta0/db2` for which I wrote the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
TMP_STORAGE="/mnt/blumeta0/db2"
METADATA_PATH="/head"
sqllib_files_folders=$(find $TMP_STORAGE$METADATA_PATH/home/db2inst1/sqllib/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 '(' '(' -type d -printf '%p/ ' ')' -o -printf '%p ' ')')
sqllib_files_folders=echo ${sqllib_files_folders//$TMP_STORAGE/}
echo $sqllib_files_folders
```

This works for string which does not have `/`. I have tried escaping with `\`. But that does not work either. Any help please?

Comment: You should store the paths in an array instead of relying on them not containing spaces, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356779/how-can-i-store-the-find-command-results-as-an-array-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
sqllib_files_folders=$(echo $sqllib_files_folders|sed "s%$TMP_STORAGE%%g")
```

Answer (score 1):

2 ideas come to mind:

1. cd to the directory first so the prefix is not in the `find` output in the first place:

   ```
   sqllib_files_folders=$(cd "$TMP_STORAGE" && find ./"$METADATA_PATH"/home/db2inst1 ...)
   ```
2. backslash escape the slashes for the parameter expansion replacement (this one's a mouthful):

   ```
   sqllib_files_folders=${sqllib_files_folders//${TMP_STORAGE//\//\\/}/}
   # ...........................................^^...........^^^^^^^^^
   ```