# How to execute command on files with spaces in them?

Tags: bash, filesystems, jpeg, webp

I am dealing with a legacy codebase where we're trying to convert all jpeg/png files to webp format using the `cwebp` command. Unfortunately, a lot of the image files were saved with spaces in the name. 
Example: `i am poorly named.jpg`

So when running the following bash script to find all jpegs in the directory and loop through and convert them the words separated by spaces are treated as another file so the image never gets converted. 
We don't want to remove the whitespaces, but just create a webp file with the exact same name.

```
files=$(find ./ -type f -name  "*.jpg")
for jpg in $files
do
  webp="${jpg/%jpg/webp}";
  if [ ! -f $webp ]; then
    echo "The webp version does not exist";
    cwebp -q 80 "$jpg" -o "$webp";
  fi
done
```

I've tried placing `jpg=$(printf '%q' "$jpg")` immediately after the `do` in the above code as well as other things.

I expect `i am poorly named.webp` to be created if file `i am poorly named.jpg` exists.

Comment: double quote `webp` in if [ ! -f "$webp" ]; then`

Comment: Is this duplicate covering your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/23356779/3266847 (Apart from what PS. is pointing out, that is.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But there is no real reason to store all filenames. So an alternative is:

```
find ./ -type f -name  "*.jpg" | while read jpg
do 
....
```

But this works only, if a filename contains no linefeed. For files with linesfeeds there are other solutions. Ask for it if needed.

Comment: Storing or looping directly - it's a duplicate either way. Please mark exact duplicates instead of answering them.

Comment: @Wiimm Duplicate aside. Thank you!