# Bash: how to extract longest directory paths from an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, find

I put the output of `find` command into array like this:

```
pathList=($(find /foo/bar/ -type d))
```

How to extract the longest paths found in the array if the array contains several equal-length longest paths?:

```
echo ${pathList[@]}
/foo/bar/raw/
/foo/bar/raw/2020/
/foo/bar/raw/2020/02/
/foo/bar/logs/
/foo/bar/logs/2020/
/foo/bar/logs/2020/02/
```

After extraction, I would like to assign `/foo/bar/raw/2020/02/`  and `/foo/bar/logs/2020/02/` to another array.

Thank you

Comment: wrt `I put the output of find command into array like this:` - don't do that as it's not robust, e.g. it'll fail when your directory names contain spaces. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/23356779/1745001 for how to populate an array with the output of a command. Also, define "longest" - most total characters or must sub-directories or something else?

Comment: Could you please confirm once on definition of longest path you want to get, I considered that you need output as per directory levels please confirm here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, yes by "longest path" I meant directory levels. Your solution works well, therefore I accepted it as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following. This should print the longest array(could be multiple in numbers same maximum length ones), you could assign it to later an array to.

```
echo "${pathList[@]}" |
awk -F'/' '{max=max>NF?max:NF;a[NF]=(a[NF]?a[NF] ORS:"")$0} END{print a[max]}'
```

---

---

I just created a test array with values provided by you and tested it as follows:

```
arr1=($(printf '%s\n' "${pathList[@]}" |\
awk -F'/' '{max=max>NF?max:NF;a[NF]=(a[NF]?a[NF] ORS:"")$0} END{print a[max]}'))
```

When I see new array's contents they are as follows:

```
echo  "${arr1[@]}"
/foo/bar/raw/2020/02/
/foo/bar/logs/2020/02/
```

***Explanation of `awk` code:*** Adding detailed explanation for `awk` code.

```
awk -F'/' '                        ##Starting awk program from here and setting field separator as / for all lines.
{
  max=max>NF?max:NF                ##Creating variable max and its checking condition if max is greater than NF then let it be same else  set its value to current NF value.
  a[NF]=(a[NF]?a[NF] ORS:"")$0     ##Creating an array a with index of value of NF and keep appending its value with new line to it.
}
END{                               ##Starting END section of this program.
  print a[max]                     ##Printing value of array a with index of variable max.
}'
```

Comment: just a followup question - I tried to loop through arr1 and it appears that it contains only 1 item instead of two. How would you separate those two directory paths in arr1 so that they become two separate items? Thank you.

Comment: @kamokoba, could you please check my arr1 answer now and lemme know I am not on my desk as of now so didn't test should work but, lemme know

Comment: it works now after adding additional parentheses. Thank you, appreciate your time!