# Putting files in directory into array variable

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, ls

I'm writing bash code that will search for specific files in the directory it is run in and add them into an array variable.  The problem I am having is formatting the results.  I need to find all the compressed files in the current directory and display both the names and sizes of the files in order of last modified.  I want to take the results of that command and put them into an array variable with each line element containing the file's name and corresponding size but I don't know how to do that.  I'm not sure if I should be using command "find" instead of "ls" but here is what I have so far:

```
find_files="$(ls -1st --block-size=MB)"
arr=( ($find_files) )
```

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: See also [BashFAQ/003](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)

Comment: There's still the issue of finding the right command.  The closest one I've found was    
 (find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@\t%f\n" | sort -n | cut -f2-).  But this command doesn't display the MB size

Comment: define 'compressed files'? please provide an example of a directory of files (with and without some 'compressed' files), then provide the expected array contents (eg, an associative array where the indices are the filenames and the values are the MBs?); what if the MB value is not a nice round number (eg, 1,325.27 MB) ... store the integer value, the real value, include commas?

Comment: Compressed files meaning any file that is either a .zip, .bz, .lzma, .xz, or .gz file

Comment: `arr=( $(anything) )` is an antipattern. See [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29).

Comment: ...if you want to read a stream into an array, use `readarray` or `mapfile` if you have a modern version bash, or a `while read` loop if you don't.

Comment: ...btw, your best answer here will depend on whether you're guaranteed to have a GNU version of `find` (with `-printf`, to tell it to customize its output format).

Comment: BTW, [How can I store the “find” command results as an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356779) is closely related; if you didn't have the size requirement, I'd be tagging this duplicate -- it's probably worth reading even absent that.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these solutions work, and were tested via copy paste from this post.

The first is fairly slow. One problem is external program invocations within a loop - `date` for example, is invoked for *every* file. You could make it quicker by not including the date in the output array (see Notes below). Particularly for method 2 - that would result in no *external* command invocations inside the `while` loop. But method 1 is really the problem - orders of magnitude slower.

Also, somebody probably knows how to convert an epoch date to another format in `awk` for example, which could be faster. Maybe you could do the sort in `awk` too. Perhaps just keep the epoch date?

These solutions are `bash` / GNU heavy and not portable to other environments (bash here strings, `find` `-printf`). OP tagged `linux` and `bash` though, so GNU can be assumed.

**Solution 1 - capture *any* compressed file - using `file` to match (slow)**

- The criteria for 'compressed' is if `file` output contains the word `compress`
- Reliable enough, but perhaps there is a conflict with some other file type description?
- `file -l | grep compress` (file 5.38, Ubuntu 20.04, WSL) indicates for me there are no conflicts at all (all files listed are compression formats)
- I couldn't find a way of classifying *any* compressed file other than this
- I ran this on a directory containing 1664 files - time (real) was **40 seconds**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Capture all files, recursively, in $TARGET, that are
# compressed files. In an indexed array. Using file name
# extensions to match.

# Initialise variables, and check the target is valid
declare -g c= compressed_files= path= TARGET=$1
[[ -r "$TARGET" ]] || exit 1

# Make the array
# A here string (<<<) must be used, to keep array in the global environment
while IFS= read -r -d '' path; do
    [[ "$(file --brief "${path%% *}")" == *compress* ]] &&
    compressed_files[c++]="${path% *} $(date -d @${path##* })"
done < \
    <(
        find "$TARGET" -type f -printf '%p %s %T@\0' |
        awk '{$2 = ($2 / 1024); print}' |
        sort -n -k 3
    )

# Print results - to test
printf '%s\n' "${compressed_files[@]}"
```

**Solution 2 - use *file extensions* - orders of magnitude faster**

- If you know exactly what extensions you are looking for, you can
  compose them in a `find` command
- This is *alot* faster
- On the same directory as above, containing 1664 files - time (real) was 200 miliseconds
- This example looks for `.gz`, `.zip`, and `.7z` (gzip, zip and 7zip respectively)
- I'm not sure if `-type f -and -regex '.*[.]\(gz\|zip\|7z\) -and printf` may be faster again, now I think of it. I started with globs cause I assumed that was quicker
- That may also allow for storing the extension list in a variable..
- This method avoids a `file` analysis on *every* file in your target
- It also makes the while loop shorter - you're only iterating *matches*
- Note the repetition of `-printf` here, this is due to the logic that
  find uses: `-printf` is 'True'. If it were included by itself, it would
  act as a 'match' and print all files
- It has to be used as a *result* of a name match being true (using `-and`)
- Perhaps somebody has a better composition?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Capture all files, recursively, in $TARGET, that are
# compressed files. In an indexed array. Using file name
# extensions to match.

# Initialise variables, and check the target is valid
declare -g c= compressed_files= path= TARGET=$1
[[ -r "$TARGET" ]] || exit 1

while IFS= read -r -d '' path; do
    compressed_files[c++]="${path% *} $(date -d @${path##* })"
done < \
    <(
        find "$TARGET" \
            -type f -and -name '*.gz'  -and -printf '%p %s %T@\0' -or \
            -type f -and -name '*.zip' -and -printf '%p %s %T@\0' -or \
            -type f -and -name '*.7z'  -and -printf '%p %s %T@\0' |
        awk '{$2 = ($2 / 1024); print}' |
        sort -n -k 3
    )

# Print results - for testing
printf '%s\n' "${compressed_files[@]}"
```

**Sample output (of either method):**

```
$ comp-find.bash /tmp
/tmp/comptest/websters_english_dictionary.tmp.tar.gz 265.148 Thu Sep 10 07:53:37 AEST 2020
/tmp/comptest/What_is_Systems_Architecture_PART_1.tar.gz 1357.06 Thu Sep 10 08:17:47 AEST 2020
```

**Note:**

- You can add a literal `K` to indicate the block size / units (kilobytes)
- If you want to print the path only from this array, you can use suffix removal: `printf '%s\n' "${files[@]&& *}"`
- For no date in the array (it's used to sort, but then its job may be done), simply remove  `$(date -d @${path##* })` (incl. the space).
- Kind of tangential, but to use different date formats, replace `$(date -d @${path##* })` with:
  `$(date -I -d @${path##* })` ISO format - note that short opts style: `date -Id @[date]` did not work for me
  `$(date -d @${path##* } +%Y-%M-%d_%H-%m-%S)` like ISO, but w/ seconds
  `$(date -d @${path##* } +%Y-%M-%d_%H-%m-%S)` same again, but w/ nanoseconds (`find` gives you nano seconds)

Sorry for the long post, hopefully it's informative.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what format you want the array to be in, but here is a snippet that creates an associative array keyed by filename with the size as the value:

```
$ ls -l test.{zip,bz2}
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 Sep 10 13:27 test.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 0 Sep 10 13:26 test.zip

$ declare -A sizes; while read SIZE FILENAME ; do sizes["$FILENAME"]="$SIZE"; done < <(find * -prune -name '*.zip' -o -name *.bz2  | xargs stat -c "%Y %s %N" | sort | cut -f 2,3 -d " ")

$ echo "${sizes[@]@A}"
declare -A sizes=(["'test.zip'"]="0" ["'test.bz2'"]="0" )

$
```

And if you just want an array of literally "filename size" entries, that's even easier:

```
$ while read SIZE FILENAME ; do sizes+=("$FILENAME $SIZE"); done < <(find * -prune -name '*.zip' -o -name *.bz2  | xargs stat -c "%Y %s %N" | sort | cut -f 2,3 -d " ")

$ echo "${sizes[@]@A}"
declare -a sizes=([0]="'test.zip' 0" [1]="'test.bz2' 0")

$
```