# Azure yml - Search folder recursively in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

In azure.yml script, I would like to recursively search for a folder that ends with _test in *$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)*

So far, tried out

```
[ -d "**/$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/?(*_test)" ]
```

and

```
 [ -d "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*_test" ]
```

However, both patterns are not working.

Is it possible to do recursive search for a folder in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)?

Can you please suggest a suitable method to search for folders ending with _test in *$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)*?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Yamuna, Does the updated answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for folders ending with _test in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) in azure.yml script, please try the following yaml sample.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- pwsh: Get-ChildItem -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -Recurse -Directory -Name -Include "**_test"
```

**Update**>>
[Microsoft-hosted Ubuntu agent](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md) has installed PowerShell tools, so PowerShell is available in it.
If you prefer to use Bash script, this command `find $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -name "**_test" -type d` will output the target folders path.

Please note that there might be multiple folders, you could use following script to assign the result to variable.

```
- bash: |
    result=$(find $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -name "**_test" -type d)
    echo "$result"
```

Or you could assign the result to array by reference to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356779/how-can-i-store-the-find-command-results-as-an-array-in-bash).

```
- bash: |
    readarray -d '' result_array < <(find $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -name "**_test" -type d)
    echo "$result_array"
```

Comment: Thank you the suggestion!
Powershell is not available in the hosted agent. Hence I am getting "command not found" error.

Comment: I am planning to use bash command  "find" to verify if _test folder is present.
I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work

UNIT_TEST=$(find . -name "*_test")
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=UNIT_TEST]$UNIT_TEST"

Please let me know how to get output of bash in a variable.Thank you!

Comment: Hi Yamuna, I have updated my answer for your reference. Please note that the result cannot be assigned to variable via ```echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=UNIT_TEST]$UNIT_TEST"``` because they are different data structure. You could try to iterate through the array to assign its elements to different variables.

Comment: Hi @Edward Han-MSFT,
result=$(find $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -name "**_test" -type d) worked for me. Thank you for the support!