# for loop displays all elements of array instead of single element

Tags: bash

Using bash to list the files that match a find command and loop through them one at a time.  Problem is, the loop displays all elements of the array instead of single element.

```
    declare poslogs=$(find /opt/upload/archive/ -name "pospoll*" -mtime -3 -printf '%f\n')
    for i in ${poslogs[@]}; do
        unzip -p /opt/upload/archive/$i $poslogfn.${reg}* \
        | grep -B5 "$trans" | grep -o "TransactionType.*" > $resultfile.poslog
    done
```

Result is

```
+ declare 'poslogs=pospoll.1699.20211011230928.zip
pospoll.1699.20211012233221.zip
pospoll.1699.20211013232932.zip'
  for i in '"${poslogs[@]}"'
+ unzip -p '/opt/upload/archive/pospoll.1699.20211011230928.zip
pospoll.1699.20211012233221.zip
pospoll.1699.20211013232932.zip' 'PosLog.1.*'
```

Result should be

```
++ find /opt/upload/archive/ -name 'pospoll*' -mtime -3 -printf '%f\n'
+ declare 'poslogs=pospoll.1699.20211011230928.zip
pospoll.1699.20211012233221.zip
pospoll.1699.20211013232932.zip'
  for i in '"${poslogs[@]}"'
+ unzip -p '/opt/upload/archive/pospoll.1699.20211011230928.zip 'PosLog.1.*'
```

Comment: Arrays are created with `declare -a`.

Comment: `var=$(...)` creates a string; you want `var=($(...))`. Or, even better, a technique from the duplicate.

Comment: @choroba - Thanks, missed that when typing this up - even with declare -a - it still fails in the exact same way.  I am using bash 4.3 so I am going to take SO's suggested answer and explore over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356779/how-can-i-store-the-find-command-results-as-an-array-in-bash

Comment: You also need the parentheses `var=(...)` and double quote the `"${poslogs[@]}"`.