# Store the results of "find" in an array (without using read)

Tags: bash

I'm trying to recreate the script from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23357277/15051374) answer but without using `read`. I tried something like:

```
pids=()
for i in $(find /mnt/c/Projekte/test/pids/ -iname "*.pid")
do
    pids+=("$i")
done

declare -p $pids
```

But that only results in this:

```
./test.sh: line 9: declare: /mnt/c/Projekte/test/pids/a1.pid: not found
```

The test folder I created looks like this:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vitus vitus   0 Mar  2 16:54 a1.pid
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vitus vitus   0 Mar  2 16:54 a2.pid
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vitus vitus   0 Mar  2 16:54 a3.pid
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vitus vitus  61 Mar  2 16:54 fill.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vitus vitus 121 Mar  8 11:48 test.sh
```

Comment: What you are trying to do can't be made to work reliably.  You need to use `read`, or do the processing within `find` by using the `-exec` option.  If you run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on the code it reports the problem and provides links to explanations of what is wrong, and what to do about it.  Also see [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for excellent information about this.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `read`?

Comment: @pjh I'm trying to avoid `read` because the script should run automatically without requiring additional keyboard input and afaik `read` requires keyboard input?

Comment: `afaik read requires keyboard input?` No, read requires _input_, it could be input from keyboard, but it also can be input _from the output of `find`_. In shell `|` and `<` are some operators used for redirecting input.

Comment: Ahh alright. Then I misunderstood the purpose of `read`. I encountered a different problem when trying the soltution from the post I linked in my question and thought that it was linked to `read` requiring keyboard input.

Comment: @Icoryx, as @KamilCuk has explained, `read` takes its input from standard input.  It could be coming from a keyboard, a file, a pipe, a fifo, a socket, or various other sources.  It looks from other comments that you are stuck with Bash 3.  In that case the best code for you to use is the `while IFS= read -r -d '' a ...` code provided by @KamilCuk.  It's rock solid.  As always, run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on your finished code to ensure that no other common issues have slipped in.

Comment: The best resource for information about reading line-by-line in Bash is [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file \(data stream, variable\) line-by-line \(and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).  One of the examples covers reading output from `find`.   Most of the code that you will find in other places (including in accepted and/or extravagantly upvoted answers on Stackoverflow) doesn't work in general (or at all in some cases).

Answer (score 1):

To print a variable pass variable name.

```
declare -p pids
```

Using a loop on word-splitted result of a command to then properly quote it when adding to an array is odd. Just load it straight to an array.

```
 pids=($(find ....))
```

Note that you might want to set `IFS=$'\n'` before word splitting takes place, and you might want to research quoting and word splitting and filename expansion in shell.

---

Either way, you should do something along:

```
readarray -d '' -t pids < <(find /mnt/c/Projekte/test/pids/ -iname "*.pid" -print0)
```

or with while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' a; do
   pids+=("$a")
done < <(find /mnt/c/Projekte/test/pids/ -iname "*.pid" -print0)
```

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: I get an error from the line declare and it works without it. Excellent thank you

Comment: If I can just populate the array by doing `pids=($(find ....))` why does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54561526/15051374) guy do it with `readarray` instead? I can't use `readarray` because I don't have bash 4.0.

Comment: `ou might want to research quoting and word splitting and filename expansion in shell.` because otherwise it undergoes word splitting and filename expansion. It will break on filenames with spaces and on filenames with `*`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got Bash 4.0 or later you can reliably populate the `pids` array without using `find`.  Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s dotglob
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nocaseglob
shopt -s nullglob

pids=( /mnt/c/Projekte/test/pids/**/*.pid )

declare -p pids
```

- `shopt -s dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.`.  `find` shows such files by default.
- `shopt -s globstar` enables the use of `**` to match paths recursively through directory trees.
- `shopt -s nocaseglob` causes globs to match in a case-insensitive fashion (like `find` option `-iname` versus `-name`).
- `shopt -s nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- The `shopt` commands can be combined into one if preferred: `shopt -s dotglob globstar nocaseglob nullglob`.
- Note that **this code might fail on versions of Bash prior to 4.3** because symlinks are (stupidly) followed while expanding `**` patterns.

Comment: Unfortunately the system the script should run on does not have Bash 4.0 and cannot be updated atm :/