# Bash array containing output from 'find' function is incorrectly structured

Tags: bash

I am trying to create an array in bash that contains filenames for a subset of files stored in a single folder. I want the array to contain only filenames with the common string "zzz", and I want the array to contain one filename per element. I have been trying to use the `find` function to get filenames containing "zzz", and store the results in `myarray`.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
# Define folder containing files
file_dir=./my_files

# Define the common string
pattern="*zzz*"

# Store find output to myarray
readarray -d ' ' -t myarray < <(find ${file_dir} -name ${pattern})

# Print myarray
echo $myarray
```

Output:

```
./my_files/abc_zzz_1.nii.gz ./my_files/def_zzz_763.nii.gz ./my_files/ghi_zzz_628.nii.gz
```

`myarray` contains the correct filenames, however it does not appear to be structured in a way that allows indexing - I would like to be able to index the nth filename in `myarray` with `${myarray[n]}`, however it seems that the full output from `find` is stored in a single element. `echo ${myarray[0]}` prints the same output as above, while `echo ${myarray[1]}` prints an empty line.

I figured that the whole output from `find` was being stored as a single string in `${myarray[0]}`, so I tried to break the string up using:

```
read -r -a myarray2 <<< "${myarray[0]}"
```

...but this did not work as intended, because echo `${myarray2}` only returns a single filename.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove the `-d '  '`, quote your variables and Put a valid shebang and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: If you do it _right_, `echo "$myarray"` will show only the first element. Use `declare -p myarray` to print your whole array in unambiguous form.

Comment: Also, the only character that can't exist in a file name is the NUL byte, so you should use `find -print0` and `readarray -d ''`. Neither spaces nor newlines are suitable.

Comment: Thanks, both. Simply removing `-d ' ' ` worked.

Comment: [How can I store the "find" command results as an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23356779/3266847) has all bases covered for getting `find` output into an array.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The slash character (`/`) also cannot exist in a `filename`. You probably meant `pathname`.

Comment: Yes, obviously, since find emits pathnames unless a particular GNU extension is used to avoid that.